# Accordion inside Bootstrap navbar dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please refer: [APEC Energy](http://www.apecenergy.co.uk/)

In the right corner, there is a user icon. On clicking it, we can see an accordion in the dropdown menu. How can this be achieved?

I have put together a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnqvnhsm/1/) with the basic code. I removed all my trials of the accordion because whatever I tried only breaks the code.

My code for the navbar:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<div id="gxcpl" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg hidden-md" href="#">Living Ahimsa</a>
            <a class="hidden-sm hidden-xs" href="#">
                <img class="gxcpl-logo" src="assets/images/logo.png" />
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> Bio Homes</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Innovation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Future</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> Bio Energy</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">BIO Heating</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BIO Lighting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BIO Air</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BIO Frequency</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> Bio Water</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Whole House Filter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reverse Osmosis</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portable Filters</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portable Storage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rain Water Storage</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> Bio Garden</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Bio Grow System</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bio Watering System</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Indoor Growing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Organic Seeds</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Organic Plants</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> Bio Health</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Core Health</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Oils</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Raw Foods</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Natural Supplements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Protien</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Shopping Basket</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Call Request</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Login/Register</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Navigation -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSFiddle seems to have accordion menu. I don't understand, what behaviour is missing?

Comment: no it doesn't... I have to put a form each in Shopping cart, Contact Us and Call request... (please see the dropdown of the menu with user icon)... so Shopping cart, Contact Us and Call Request need to be the title... Shopping cart will be open, while if Contact US or Call Request is clicked, the accordian kicks in...